# Click event doesn't work while trying to dynamically add elements to <ul> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a list in which after you click on it there are added new li tags into it but nothing happens after you click li tag.
When I try to do it this way:

```
$('ul').click(function(){

    $("ul").append('<li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>');
    }).children().click(function(e) {
       return false;
    });
```

Everything seems ok. When I click on list body new element is added and when I click on previously declared li tag nothing happens. But after clicking on element newly added to the list another new element is being added. 
Why is that and what can I do about it?

Comment: You are canceling clicks on li... Are you expecting something to happen when you click on the li?

Comment: Why even bind an event handler to the li's?

Comment: Because without it after you click on li the new li is created. I don't want that. I just want to create li's after clicking on ul's body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code only applies the `.click(function(e) { return false; });` handler to those children that already existed when you applied the other click handler.

jQuery supports a dynamic event binding approach that will automatically bind the handler to new nodes:

```
$('ul')
.on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).append('<li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>');
})
.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
   return false;
});
```

This should bind a click event to `ul` that creates a new `li`, while also binding an event handler for all `li`s under the `ul` no matter if they are dynamically created or not.

You can read more about the `.on` method in the [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

```js
$('ul')
.on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).append('<li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>');
})
.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
   return false;
});
```

```css
ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when i use code that you provided nothing happens after I click on the list, no new elements are being added

Comment: I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLybzcyr/) demonstrating it does in fact work. Click the bullet point region and it will create a new `li`.

Comment: Ok it does work, I was just using 1.6 version of jQuery :P. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While Brendan's answer is valid I suggest to get rid of the second function and use following approach instead:

```js
$('ul')
.on('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target === this){
       $(this).append('<li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>');
    }
})
```

```css
ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('ul')
.on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).append('<li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>');
})
.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
   alert();
});
```

```css
ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```